# By pressing Insert key to open div id in a form using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am having a form which contains 2 div tag. one div tag is open default and another tag is hide. by pressing insert key to open  that div tag. i have tried but not getting the correct output,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="default" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Controller_page/add_sales_others/'.$this->session->userdata('cus_id'));?>">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="col-xs-14 col-md-10  col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 ">
            <div style="width:100%; align:left; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <!--table class="table table-bordered"-->
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover metable table-bordered" id="nm">
                    <tr border="#ccc" ;>
                        <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" /></th>
                        <!--th>S.No</th-->
                        <th width="340px" ;>Item Name</th>
                        <th width="60px" ;>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Vat %</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <!--th>Action</th-->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10px" ;><input type='checkbox' class='case' /></td>      <!--td width = "20px";><span id='snum'>1.</span></td-->
                        <td>
                            <b><input class="form-control" type='text' id='itemname_1' name='itemname[]' autofocus /></b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td_class" width="40px" ;>
                            <b><input class="form-control" type='text' id='quantity_no_1' name='quantity_no[]' /></b>
                            <input type='hidden' name='customer_id_1' id='customer_id_1' value='<?php echo $this->session->userdata('cus_id') ?>' class='form-control' />
                            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='supplier_id_1' name='supplier_id[]' />
                            <input type="hidden" id="dummy_itemnum" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="dummy_itemname" />
                        </td>

                        <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled maxlength="200" id='vat_no_1' name='vat_no[]' value="" /></b></td>
                        <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled maxlength="200" id='rate_no_1' name='rate_no[]' /></b> </td>
                        <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled id='total_no_1' name='total_no[]' /></b> </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

script code:

I have attached the script code which i tried, please check it and do my needs,

```
    $("#sideform").hide();
    jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'Insert',function() {
        $("#sideform").show();
        $("#nm").hide();
          return false;
        });
```

when i pressing the insert key side form get show(opened) and id = nm tag get to closed. Thanks@

Comment: Did you see my answer ?

Comment: ya its working Thanks@ but tab key is not working by the same code

Comment: If you found the answer usefull please feel free to upvote. If the answer works please mark as answer so other users can see that it was the solution for your problem. 

Does the tab key has to do the same as insert?

Comment: am having the form which contain 2 div tag. one div  id =1  tag contain table and another 
 div id = 2 tag contain some fields. by pressing insert key div id = 1 should hide and div id 2
gets show. By default, div id  =1 get show and div id = 2 gets hide. div id = 1 contain table
fields which contain several rows and columns. by pressing tab moving one another fields
 and add rows in the table dynamically (working fine). my question is At a time either tab or
 insert key is working properly but  both  the keys are not working at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Each `Key` has a unique code and you can ask if that code is being pressed (look at the `jQuery` code below). `Insert` has code `45`

```js
$("#sideform").hide();
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 45 || e.keyCode == 9) {
    $("#sideform").show();
    $("#nm").hide();
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="default" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Controller_page/add_sales_others/'.$this->session->userdata('cus_id'));?>">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="col-xs-14 col-md-10  col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 ">
      <div style="width:100%; align:left; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <!--table class="table table-bordered"-->
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover metable table-bordered" id="nm">
          <tr border="#ccc" ;>
            <th>
              <input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" />
            </th>
            <!--th>S.No</th-->
            <th width="340px" ;>Item Name</th>
            <th width="60px" ;>Quantity</th>
            <th>Vat %</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <!--th>Action</th-->
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="10px" ;>
              <input type='checkbox' class='case' />
            </td>
            <!--td width = "20px";><span id='snum'>1.</span></td-->
            <td><b><input class="form-control" type='text'    id='itemname_1' name='itemname[]' autofocus/></b>
            </td>
            <td class="td_class" width="40px" ;><b><input  class="form-control" type='text' id='quantity_no_1' name='quantity_no[]'/></b>
              <input type='hidden' name='customer_id_1' id='customer_id_1' value='' class='form-control' />
              <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='supplier_id_1' name='supplier_id[]' />
              <input type="hidden" id="dummy_itemnum" />
              <input type="hidden" id="dummy_itemname" />
            </td>

            <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled  maxlength="200" id='vat_no_1' name='vat_no[]' value=""/></b>
            </td>
            <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled  maxlength="200" id='rate_no_1' name='rate_no[]'/></b> 
            </td>
            <td width="120px" ;><b><input class="form-control" type='text' disabled id='total_no_1' name='total_no[]'/></b> 
            </td>

          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form id="sideform">show if i hit Insert</form>
```

**Note** I could not find your second `form` so i created one fast
**Note 2** I updated the code with `Tab keyCode` (That is `9`)